# How to duplicate a task, e.g. compile?

Tags: sbt

For various reasons, I have a task `enhance` triggered by `compile` because we need it to run our code and I don't want programmers to just compile and forget to enhance.

This works fine but in some cases, especially to debug the enhancer, I need a `compileOnly` task doing exactly the same thing as `compile` but without the attached trigger.

Is there a way to "clone" compile? I tried:

```
object EnhancerBuild extends Build {
  lazy val compileOnly = taskKey[Analysis]("compileOnly") in Compile

  lazy val root = Project("root", file(".")) settings(  
      compileOnly <<= compileTask
   )
}
```

But it does not find the `compilerReporter` & `compileInputs` settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, you really need another task that would mimic one of the many from sbt, e.g. `compile`. If so, see the following from `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val compileOnly = taskKey[sbt.inc.Analysis]("compileOnly")

compileOnly <<= (compile in Compile)
```

With the definition, `compileOnly` depends on `compile` in `Compile` scope.

```
> inspect compileOnly
[info] Task: sbt.inc.Analysis
[info] Description:
[info]  compileOnly
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/C:/dev/sandbox/compile-copy/}compile-copy/*:compileOnly
[info] Defined at:
[info]  C:\dev\sandbox\compile-copy\build.sbt:3
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  compile:compile
[info] Delegates:
[info]  *:compileOnly
[info]  {.}/*:compileOnly
[info]  */*:compileOnly
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine because `(compile in Compile)` is different of `compile`. So `compileOnly` does not trigger my enhancer. This is so simple that I did not thought of it.

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer when the time comes.